# Sitecore Login Issue No Users to Kick

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Has any else experienced when logging into to sitecore it says too many users are logged but when you navigate to "kick user" it says "There are no active user sessions that you can log out from Sitecore."

My user is an admin.

The only way I've found to resolve this is restarting the website in IIS which I wont want to do once the site is live.

I'm using the latest release Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if you have the right license.

Login to Sitecore and go to the Desktop.

In the start menu, go to All Applications -> system -> license details.

(You can also find license info in the Control Panel section)

Check the number of concurrent users allowed.

If this is all good and the license is valid raise a support ticket with Sitecore.

If not contact your Sitecore account manager for a new license.

Answer (score 1):

I have same version same issue and still looking for a solution.
I have only working workaround.
If you can you should add another url address and amend your host file if you cannot clear .NET framework cache located in destinations shown below:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root
or
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root
```

provided that you are using .NET v 4.0 if not change it respectively.
That will clear all your pre-rendered pages so bear in mind that any website on that server will become sluggish for a while.

**Edit:**
I've found that logged in users are not showing because call to `/api/sitecore/DomainAccessGuard/GetActiveSessions` 
results in 404.
I workaround it by adding rewrite rule

```
<rule name="Rewrite api">
    <match url="^api/sitecore(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="sitecore/shell/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

I am still trying to find the real culprit.

Comment: I can't get the sitecore query boost to work. You can add a session killer script which essentially kicks everyone off or change the session time from 20 mins to something shorter then wait...

Answer (score 0):

This view/dialog/api only provides the data from the current server.
In a loadbalanced setup this is incomplete.
So you would have to open this on each backend (cm) server to get a complete list of active sessions.
This should explain your mismatch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).